# How best to sort products on js?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have this code, but it does not work correctly.

```js
let productBox = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
let selectCategory = document.querySelector('#select-category');
let categoryVal = document.querySelectorAll('#select-category option');

selectCategory.addEventListener('change', () => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(categoryVal, catItem => {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBox, prodItem => {
            if((catItem.selected) && (prodItem.category === 
            catItem.category)) {
                prodItem.style.display = 'none'
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-category">
    <option category="all">All</option>
    <option category="dinner">Dinner</option>
    <option category="first meal">First meal</option>
    <option category="garnish">Garnish</option>
</select>

<div category="dinner" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div category="first meal" class="product">First meal</div>
<div category="garnish" class="product">Garnish</div>
```

I need that when selecting an `option` element, `display none` is applied to blocks whose category does not match. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: why don't you display:none to all other divs, except the one that is selected. What's the need of search here? ( i assume there are 3 divs only)

Comment: It is necessary to show only the `div` with which the category attribute coincides with the category attribute of the selected `option`, and hide all others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine. Let me know is it you expectation

```
<script>
let productBox = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
let selectCategory = document.querySelector('#select-category');
let categoryVal = document.querySelectorAll('#select-category option');

selectCategory.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
    var selectedValue = evt.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase();
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBox, prodItem => {
        if(selectedValue !== 'all' && (prodItem.getAttributeNode('category').value !== 
        selectedValue)) {
            prodItem.style.display = 'none'
        } else {
            prodItem.style.display = 'block'
        }           
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in your code, and your HTML is invalid.

There is no `category` attribute defined in HTML5. If you want to use custom attributes, they should be prefixed with [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*). For the `select` options, you should just use the `value` attribute.

After fixing that, the logic just needs to be:

1. Get the selected value from the `select` element if it changes.
2. Loop over the product `div` elements, and for each element:

   - if the selected category is `all`, or if it matches the `data-category` of the element, set the display style to its default (`''`)
   - otherwise set the display style to `none`.

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
const productDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
const categorySelect = document.querySelector('#select-category');

categorySelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const category = e.target.value;

  [...productDivs].forEach(pd => {
    const display = pd.dataset.category === category || category === 'all';
    pd.style.display = display ? '' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="select-category">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
  <option value="first meal">First meal</option>
  <option value="garnish">Garnish</option>
</select>

<div data-category="dinner" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div data-category="first meal" class="product">First meal</div>
<div data-category="garnish" class="product">Garnish</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selectCategory(element) {
  const value = element.value;
  const products = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(products, product => {
    const productAttr = product.getAttribute('category');
    if(value === 'All'){
      product.style.display = 'block';
      return;
    }
    productAttr !== value.toLowerCase() ? 
        product.style.display = 'none' :
        product.style.display = 'block';
  })
}
```

```html
<select id="select-category" onChange="selectCategory(this)">
    <option category="all">All</option>
    <option category="dinner">Dinner</option>
    <option category="first meal">First meal</option>
    <option category="garnish">Garnish</option>
</select>

<div category="dinner" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div category="first meal" class="product">First meal</div>
<div category="garnish" class="product">Garnish</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I renamed the `category` attributes of the options to `value`
2. I wrapped the whole code with `{}` so I can use local variables
3. I used the `input` event instead of the `change` event
4. I listen on the bubbled input event on the document, so I can check for the event on later added content
5. I used CSS class `hide` instead of setting style directly
6. I first set class of every `product` to `hide` (not for option `all`), then I unset that class for element with appropriate category value.

```js
console.clear();

{
    document.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const selectCategory = document.querySelector('#select-category');
    if (e.target === selectCategory) {
      const productBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
      const categoryVal = document.querySelectorAll('#select-category option');

      if (selectCategory.value == 'all') {
        show(productBoxes)
      } else {
        hide(productBoxes)
      }
      const matches = document.querySelectorAll(`[category*="${selectCategory.value}"]`)
      show(matches)
    }    

  })
  
  
  const hide = (items) => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, prodItem => {
      prodItem.classList.add('hide')
    })
  }
  const show = (items) => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, prodItem => {
      prodItem.classList.remove('hide')
    })
  }
  
}
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-category">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
  <option value="first meal">First meal</option>
  <option value="garnish">Garnish</option>
</select>

<div category="dinner" class="product">Dinner: One</div>
<div category="first meal" class="product">First meal</div>
<div category="garnish" class="product">Garnish: one</div>
<div category="garnish" class="product">Garnish: two</div>
<div category="dinner" class="product">Dinner: Two</div>

<div category="dinner" class="product">Dinner: three</div>

<br><br><select><option>totally<option>unrelated<option>select</select>
```